# Set initial state from an Api inside redux toolkit and React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, supabase

I need to set the initial state of my redux reducer, with a function that is getting data from an api (I'm using supabase as a backend for my app). Inside my Slice, I have this :

```
const initialState = {
    todoList: []
}



export const saveTodo = createSlice({
    name: 'manageList',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addTodoToList: (state, action) => {
            state.todoList.push({ name: action.payload, isDone: false, isRemoved: false })
        },
        checkTodoToList: (state, action) => {
            state.todoList.map((todo, index) => {
                if (index === action.payload) {
                    if (todo.isDone == true) {
                        todo.isDone = false
                    } else {
                        todo.isDone = true
                    }

                }
                return todo
            })
        },
        removeTodoToList: (state, action) => {



            state.todoList = state.todoList.filter((todo, index) => index !== action.payload)


        }

    }
})
```

Now I would like to find the best approach to set that empty array with the return of this function:

```
async function getProfile() {
    try {

        const user = supabase.auth.user()

        let { data, error, status } = await supabase
            .from('todos')
            .select(`name,isDone,isDeleted`)
            .single()

        if (error && status !== 406) {
            throw error
        }

        if (data) {
            return data
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } finally {

    }
}
```

How's the best way to set that data inside the todoList [] ?
Thanks